# Azure free trial: requests blocked even though I still have the full $200 credit

Tags: azure

I have started a Microsoft Azure free trial a week ago and I have been successfully using the Cognitive Services with the Speech API for the first few days.

But now it doesn't work anymore: when I make a text-to-speech request, I receive an empty file without any warning.

In the Metrics panel, I can see that I have "Blocked Calls" which means that Azure considers that I have exceeded the "quota or rate" limit. It can't be the rate as I don't make multiple requests at once. I probably have exceeded the free quota limit but if I did, Azure should not block my requests but deduce my usage from the $200 credit (170€).

So in brief: I don't understand why my requests are blocked while I still have $200 of credit.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure support team solved the problem: I had to switch my service from F0 to S0

1. On the dashboard, select your resource for which you want to go above the free limit.
2. Then on the left pane select "Pricing tier"
3. Select S0 and save

S0 is activated right away so as soon as I selected it, my request were no longer refused.

[image]

By the way Azure support team responded very quickly (within a couple of hours and once even minutes), and I was impressed by their detailed and personalized answers.